# Issue rebuilding dist and do hot reload with an angular universal app

Tags: docker, nestjs, angular-universal, hot-reload

I have bootstrapped a dockerized Angular universal app along with a Nestjs app. Lauching docker-compose.yml launches the back on localhost:3000 and the front on localhost:4000§.

Making a change in the app.component.html doesn't seem to impact the ui. Probably the dist folder not regenerated the good way, and maybe an option missing for hot-reload.

Huge thanks for anyone having a bootstraped nest angular universal dockerized project available on github. Thank you for your help !

Tried to set "liveReload": true in the angular.json file, but it's not enough. Even rerun docker-compose file doesn't show the changes. Guess i miss a rebuild of the front within a dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to test it with

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:ssr"]
```

in docker file?

Comment: it doesn't seem to create the expected change, thank you for trying